# How do I use a database in Windows Mobile 6.5

Tags: sql, mobile, windows-mobile

I am currently developing an application for a Motorola enterprise mobility device which has Windows Mobile 6.5. I am developing the application using Visual Studio 2008 Mobile Development Kit using C#.

My problem is this :

I want to use a database for this application. But I have no idea how to use a database in a mobile device. I tried googling and even searching on this site but could not find a proper way to do it.  While searching how to do this I came across this "SQL Anywhere Developer Edition" but I have no idea about it.

Could you please suggest the best way to have a database in the mobile application itself (not using client like SQL Server in the mobile) or any other way.

Answer (score 4):

You want [Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 for Windows Mobile](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=12264).

Comment: But if i use this i have to installe the compact 3.5 to the phone it self right..? But is there anyway to have the database inside the app it self without using a client...?

Comment: I'm not sure about the need for the Compact Framework. You night want to check out SQL Lite. See this comparison... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/583278/sqlite-vs-sqlce-vs-in-a-mobile-application

Comment: yeah theanks for the reply...But the database i want is a small database not a big one...If i explain the requirement of me more...1.I need the simplest,.easiest and use friendly database solution....2.I want to synch the database with a remote database(Local databse is only used to keep temporary data) ...>So far I have got 3.5 compact edition...sql lite as answers...If anyone can give me answer considering above requirements it would be a great help as if i get the answer i can derectly try that....Thanks for replying everyone...

Comment: I can appreciate the desire for lightweight. We ended up dropping SQL CE for a home-grown object store based on BplusTree (http://sourceforge.net/projects/bplusdotnet/), but that was for C#.

Comment: hmm then its better if i will start with sqllite it self. I am also developing the application using C#...DO you have any idea about the SQL Anywhere Developer Edition ...??Thanks for the help... Really appreciate it

Comment: Thanks for the help again. I will try sql lite first and will update the results,,,,thanks again